# FILE privilege to MySQL session/user

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1045

When someone is registerd in my MySQL database, this function must work:

```
mysql_query("SELECT mail 
               FROM users 
               INTO OUTFILE 'test.txt'");
```

But I get the error

> Access denied for user 'registerdb'@'%' (using password: YES)

So how I give the FILE writing permission to the session/user?

Comment: MySQL will not overwrite a file that already exists as a security precaution. It will only create NEW files.

Answer (score 12):

Chek for permissions of that user:

> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'registerdb'@'%'

If there no listed FILE permission, just add it:

> GRANT FILE ON *.* to 'registerdb'@'%'

and then:

> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

But beware for by doing granting the FILE permission on `*.*` you are essentially [giving that user full access to any file the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552206/grant-file-on-just-one-database/13552253#13552253).

To limit [limit the location in which files can be read and written, set the secure_file_priv system to a specific directory](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file).

Comment: Great answer. Should be at the top, not the other one.

Comment: but beware for by doing grant file on \*.\* you are essentially giving that user full file access to anything via the server. Make sure you trust him/her THAT much

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the file outside of MySQL first, there is **no function** in MySQL that can delete or overwrite a file.
This is a security measure and you should be thankful for that fact.

Note that it can be tricky to figure out where exactly MySQL stores its files.

I usually use

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'nonexistingfile' INTO validtable
```

The error that generates, gives you the full path for the current database that `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` will write to.
You can use a variety of ways to delete (or better move) the file, a `cron-job` comes to mind.
You could even write a custom UDF that will do the deleting for you although that is a mayor security risk and programmers who do this deserve a fate worse than something horrid.

Another option is to do

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @today:= CURDATE();
INSERT INTO saved_mail_log (filename, whensaved, user_id) 
  VALUES (CONCAT(@today,'mailsave.csv'), @today, '1234');
SELECT mail FROM users WHERE user_id = '1234' INTO OUTFILE CONCAT(@today,'mailsave.csv');
COMMIT;
```

I'm not 100% sure you can use a function to create the `OUTFILE` parameter, if not you will have to select that value and inject it into the query using dynamic SQL.

You can get the latest file using:

```
SELECT * FROM saved_mail_log WHERE user_id = '1234' ORDER BY whensaved DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I still couldn't use the query 

     sql_query("SELECT mail 
               FROM users 
               INTO OUTFILE 'test.txt'");

even when the file doens't exist....

So the solution must be to give the rights to my session/user, but how do I have to do that?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using??