# `GRANT FILE ON` just one database

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sql-grant, mysql-error

I want to allow LOAD DATA command for the john mysql user.  So I logged into mysql terminal as root and issued the following statement:

```sql
GRANT FILE ON johndatabase.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

But I got the following error:

> ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES

If I replaced `johndatabase.*` with `*.*`, then everything works.  But doesn't `*.*` mean all databases?   I want to limit the john mysql user to just johndatabase.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can't grant FILE privileges on just a single database. That logically doesn't make any sense. Consider what [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//privileges-provided.html#priv_file) say:

> The FILE privilege gives you permission to read and write files on the
>   server host using the LOAD DATA INFILE and SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE
>   statements and the LOAD_FILE() function. A user who has the FILE
>   privilege can read any file on the server host that is either
>   world-readable or readable by the MySQL server. (This implies the user
>   can read any file in any database directory, because the server can
>   access any of those files.)

Thus, the FILE privilege is a *global* privilege. It affects all files on the server and allows access only to global commands (e.g. `LOAD DATA INFILE`, etc...), not scoped to any database. The only way to grant FILE privileges is on all databases, using this syntax:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Where do you use the GRANT FILE query syntax ive not seen any example code on SO with it being used to explain how its done, as i need to grant file for outfile use. Then i need to deny file after outfile is finished.

Comment: To clarify, it makes _logical_ sense to wish to restrict the FILE privilege to one database. But that would give a false sense of security. Only the most trusted users should get it.

Answer (score 0):

With the FILE privilege, you give a user access to the filesystem that the mysql server can access. Because of this, it's useless to limit it to a specific database, as the user will be able to access all databases on filesystem level. That's why, it can only be set on `*.*`.

Answer (score 0):

You should grant [FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) on all the tables in all databases (`*.*`) as shown below:

```sql
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'user';
```

Actually, [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-databases) says below:

> Because any static global privilege is considered a privilege for all databases, ...

And, you cannot give `FILE` privilege on only one table (e.g., `person`) in all databases (`*.person`) as shown below becuase there is error:

```sql
GRANT FILE ON *.person TO 'user';
```

So, we need to grant [static global privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#privileges-provided-static) like [FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file), [PROCESS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process), [REPLICATION SLAVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_replication-slave) etc on all the tables in all databases (`*.*`) as shown below, otherwise there is error:

```sql
GRANT [STATIC_GLOBAL_PRIVILEGES] ON *.* TO <USER>;
```