# How to grant replication privilege to a database in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-replication, privileges

I need to create a user with `REPLICATION SLAVE` privilege for each database.

When I use the command:

```sql
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON `mydb`.* TO 'user';
```

The error is shown:

> Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES

Is there a way to grant `REPLICATION SLAVE` privilege to only a database?

Comment: this might be a duplicate question. please see answer [here] :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552206/grant-file-on-just-one-database

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate question. In your answer there is no solution for my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't restrict `GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE` to only one database, so you must use

### **`GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'user'@'host'`**

But you can restrict the replication itself :

- put the following command in your configuration file (*my.ini*) on the
  <s>master</s> slave:

### [`--replicate-do-db=db_name`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db)

### EDIT :

As the latter is rather for the slave server, it can easily be messed up with. So you'll want to do it on the master server, using either :
`[mysqld]`

### [**`binlog-do-db=replicated_db_name`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db)

for the databases that you want to replicate

### OR

### [**`binlog-ignore-db=ignored_db_name`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-ignore-db)

for the databases that you don't want to be replicated

- For both commands : to specify more than one database, use this
  option multiple times.

### Warning:

Excluding databases on the server using the last two commands, has the effect that no statement about them will be included in the binary log file which will compromise the backup procedure.

Comment: an otherwise less viable option is to exclude some databases on the slave by using `replicate-ignore-db=dbname` in the [mysqld] option group , it can take multiple database names, but anyone who can access the configuration file on the slave can change it.

Answer (score 0):

You should grant [REPLICATION SLAVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_replication-slave) on all the tables in all databases (`*.*`) as shown below:

```sql
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'user';
```

Actually, [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-databases) says below:

> Because any static global privilege is considered a privilege for all databases, ...

And, you cannot give `REPLICATION SLAVE` privilege on only one table (e.g., `person`) in all databases (`*.person`) as shown below becuase there is error:

```sql
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.person TO 'user';
```

So, we need to grant [static global privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#privileges-provided-static) like [REPLICATION SLAVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_replication-slave), [PROCESS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process), [FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file), etc on all the tables in all databases (`*.*`) as shown below, otherwise there is error:

```sql
GRANT [STATIC_GLOBAL_PRIVILEGES] ON *.* TO <USER>;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this instead.

```
$ mysql -h 10.20.30.1 -u user -p
mysql> CREATE USER 'repl_slave'@'10.20.30.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Passw0rdf0rRepl';
mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl_slave'@'10.20.30.1';
```